# ASP.NET Couchbase SessionState loop forever when Couchbase Server died

Tags: couchbase, session-state

I have a problem with **ASP.NET Couchbase SessionState**: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-aspnet

In the normal case everything is OK but when we **enter wrong Couchbase URL in web.config** or **Couchbase Server died** the web server **w3wp is still take resource and web server CPU jump to 100% very fast**,

Couchbase client have an **infinite loop** here and we don't know how to fix this.

Worker --> ProcessPool --> MessageStreamListener.

```
private void ReadMessages(Uri heartBeatUrl, Uri configUrl)
...
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
...
}
```

My problem seem same as topic: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/runaway-worker-process-when-cluster-node-shutdown-sessionstate-provider/610/8

Please help me.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The loop is a bug with a jira ticket [here](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBASP-20).
2. If your cluster goes down or enter invalid bootstrap urls, your going to run into issues!

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Are there anyway to workaround it at the moment?

Comment: Not currently, but this should be fixed in an up coming release.